# How can i zoom in really close to a model without this 'xray' effect?

Tags: modeling

I would like to know if there is any way that i can stop this from happening. I would like to be able to zoom as much as i want into / around a model without any of this stuff happening.

[image: X-ray like effect that prevents me from zooming up really close]

Comment: Switching to Ortho mode is easiest and fastest (numpad 5).

Comment: Press **n**. In the **View** section lower the value on the **Start clip ** distance